# Anyway to reduce memory footprint of this code?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a chunk of code here

```
//function that hides unwanted page elements based on a what is entered in  a search bar
function pageSearch() {
//when the function is called it retrieves what is entered in the search bar
//*****************variables*****************\\
var userInput = document.getElementById("boxOfSearching").value;
var fields = [];
//an array of all article tags
fields = document.getElementById("bulletin-course-listings").getElementsByTagName("li");
var holder = "";
var counter = 0;
var childArray = [];
//*****************processing and output*****************\\
    //while loop to sort through array elements
while (counter < fields.length)
{
     childArray = fields[counter].getElementsByTagName("strong");
     holder = childArray[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
     if (holder.indexOf(userInput) == -1)
     {
          fields[counter].setAttribute("style", "display:none");
     }
     else
     {
       fields[counter].setAttribute("style", "");
     }
     counter++;
}
}
```

Now, what is supposed to happen (and what does happen) is when I type something in a text box with an id called boxofsearching (that calls this function on keyup). It searches through a list of elements and grabs what's in the  tag. It then compares it to what the user input and if it doesn't contain it then it removes the element.

However, I'm using it on a list that contains several hundred elements. What happens when I type is my browser locks up and the memory usage and CPU usage spike for several seconds and then it finishes. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you planning on deleting the actual DOM elements, or just hiding them via CSS as you're doing? If you're not actually deleting them from the DOM, you can retrieve the array of elements *once*, like this:

```
var fields = array()

document.onload = function() {
    fields = document.getElementById("bulletin-course-listings").getElementsByTagName("li");
}

function pageSearch() { ... }
```

Then you can remove the definition of `fields` in the function. That should improve the performance somewhat.

Comment: Yea, I want to hide them as they need to be restored if a query that matches them is entered. That makes sense I will try that and see if it works

Comment: Alright, so that made a very noticeable difference but it still will blow up if I type too quickly.

Comment: @bomblord Regardless of how many optimizations we make, you're still ultimately executing a long loop on each keypress, which adds up quickly. So, you might want to take a different approach: set timeouts instead, like here: http://pastebin.com/AF9BPg6f  Change your keyup event handler to be `setPageSearchTimer()`. This way, if you're typing fast, there will be a short delay before the function is executed, and each key press will reset the timer. You can tweak second argument of `window.setTimeout()` (in milliseconds) until you find the value that is the best compromise for you.

Comment: @bomblord Apologies; I left some of the outdated earlier code in the first version of the pastebin link. Try it again now.

Comment: @Chris_Brendel that's another noticeable improvement but sadly it still freezes when hiding/unhiding the elements (I'm talking an entire browser lockup ). The freeze is a fraction of the time though. I may have to have it only run after hitting a submit button.

I'm thinking there are just too many elements to sort through at this point thanks for all the help up to now.

Comment: @bomblord Short of doing what you suggested with the submit button, you could also try making all changes to a clone of `#bulletin-course-listings` in the loop and then reassign the original node once you're done. It's so slow now because the DOM is being redrawn on each loop, each time you make a CSS change, and that's very complex. You could try this: http://pastebin.com/hYTeCcby  This will redraw the DOM just *once*, and should be the fastest yet. If not, your idea of going with the submit event might be the best bet.

Comment: Thanks that brought it to a reasonable level! Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your fields should be a global variable, and preferentially a simple JS object instead of a element list, like

```
fields = [{"obj1"}, {"obj2"}];
```

The `getElementsByTagName` on every keyup may be slowing it down.